# How to call a script upon button press in Flutter?

Tags: python, flutter, api, dart

Consider the simple app below:

[screenshot of example application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BklJu.png)

How do I call a script (likely a Python file, but it could even be something lower level like C/C++, etc) that can return some variable back into my Flutter app. In this example (a simple case), I am seeking to call some .py file via a button press that will return the square of the entered number. That is, the outcome would look something like this:

[screenshot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWHKg.png)

Just manipulating numbers in this way is likely something that I can do in Dart, but I can easily imagine scenarios would I would need to rely on Python packages to do more advanced manipulations. E.g., compressing a picture.

Is there are standard way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When possible, do this type of computation in Dart. You can do image manipulation with the [image](https://pub.dev/packages/image) library.

If you do need to interop with native code, you need to use [platform channels](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels).

However, if you are just making a desktop application, it may be worth just creating a sort of "local server" in Python (or similar) that handles http requests (on `localhost`), does computations, and returns some response. With this approach, your Flutter application can remain "dumb." This is great, because then all your flutter app needs to know is how to make HTTP requests to your local server and then show the results to the user.

Note: the local server approach is really only geared toward desktop. Other platforms (mobile and web) should use dart-only code or platform channels.